# How does abof.com's online 3D trial room work?

Tags: javascript, web, 3d-modelling

I'm an intermediate web designer and was really curious to know how that works. What programming language did they use and is there any library which helps in doing this?
I want to try making something like that. How do I go about it?

EDIT
Link:
http://www.abof.com/women-tops-tees
Select any top and Click on Try out button. It's only available for women.

Comment: Could you please add direct url to this "3D trial room".

Comment: Ok. I mentioned the link in Edit part.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look with Chrome's F12 tools.

You tell the website your vital-stats (height, weight, bra, etc) which the server then uses to build a 3D model, there is no indication given as to what the 3D system they're using it, it could quite possibly be something custom-made.

The t-shirts and other clothes seem to just be textures applied to the models which are rendered on the server and sent to the client by AJAX and displayed on-screen by drawing it to a `<canvas>` element. There is no client-side 3D as far as I can see.

...which is a shame, because this is something that could very easily be done using WebGL.